# three.js input type="text" not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, three.js

I am  a newbie three.js ,and I need help
A my page has navigation bar  and threejs conteiner

```
#navcontainer 
{
position:fixed;
display: block;
background-color: #303b47;
z-index:100; 
position:absolute;
}
```

navbar has a input form for search :

```
<input id="searchbt" type="text" placeholder="Search" >
```

with style:

```
#searchbt{    
    background:  #29333d url(../img/Search.png) left no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-style:none; 
    width:200px;
    height:66px; 
    color:#fff;
}
```

threejs conteiner:

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
            //var container, stats;
            var camera, controls, scene, renderer, projector;
            var cross;      
            var posN = 80; 

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {       
                var container = document.getElementById("threejs");//ищем элемент co        

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90,container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = posN;

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls (camera );
                controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

                manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
                    console.log( item, loaded, total );
                };

                var texture = new THREE.Texture();
                var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
                loader.load( './kos.jpg', function ( image ) {
                    texture.image = image;
                    texture.needsUpdate = true;
                } );

                // model
                var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
                loader.load( './skull.obj', function ( object ) {
                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                            child.material.map = texture;
                        }
                    } );
                    object.position.y = 10;
                    scene.add( object );
                } );

                //

                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                scene.add( light );

                light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
                scene.add( light );

                   // Picking stuff
                  // projector = new THREE.Projector();
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );

                 renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth , container.clientHeight);
                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }

            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( container.clientWidth , container.clientHeight );
                render();

            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                controls.update();
            }

            function render() { 
                camera.updateMatrixWorld();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
```

include how

```
    <div id="threejs" style=""> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/model.js">
```

style:

```
#threejs{
    width:100%; 
    height:500px; 
    top:100px; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 25px;
}
```

When finding the mouse on the search bar it stands out but does not work (do not enter information)
Mby anybody know ...how this correct ??

Comment: Try to add dom element to `THREE.OrbitControls( object, domElement )`